# Search for a string in all tables, rows and columns of a DB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am lost in a big database and I am not able to find where the data I get comes from. I was wondering if it is possible with SQL Server 2005 to search for a string in all tables, rows and columns of a database?

Does anybody has an idea if it is possible and how?

Comment: See this as well,,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174627/searching-text-from-db-sql-server/22854200#22854200

Comment: Also see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4039/search-all-string-columns-in-all-sql-server-databases/

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This code should do it in SQL 2005, but a few caveats:

1. It is RIDICULOUSLY slow. I tested it on a small database that I have with only a handful of tables and it took many minutes to complete. If your database is so big that you can't understand it then this will probably be unusable anyway.
2. I wrote this off the cuff. I didn't put in any error handling and there might be some other sloppiness especially since I don't use cursors often. For example, I think there's a way to refresh the columns cursor instead of closing/deallocating/recreating it every time.

If you can't understand the database or don't know where stuff is coming from, then you should probably find someone who does. Even if you can find where the data is, it might be duplicated somewhere or there might be other aspects of the database that you don't understand. If no one in your company understands the database then you're in a pretty big mess.

```
DECLARE
    @search_string  VARCHAR(100),
    @table_name     SYSNAME,
    @table_schema   SYSNAME,
    @column_name    SYSNAME,
    @sql_string     VARCHAR(2000)

SET @search_string = 'Test'

DECLARE tables_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN tables_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_schema, @table_name

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE columns_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL  -- Only strings have this and they always have it

    OPEN columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql_string = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' LIKE ''%' + @search_string + '%'') PRINT ''' + QUOTENAME(@table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ''''

        EXECUTE(@sql_string)

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    END

    CLOSE columns_cur

    DEALLOCATE columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_schema, @table_name
END

CLOSE tables_cur

DEALLOCATE tables_cur
```

Comment: "If no one in your company understands the database then you're in a pretty big mess" - yes, this is typically when the probably new and only IT person needs something like this, as management will not approve funds for doing it properly. PS. this worked ok for me on SQL server 2012.

Comment: What if all objects are not owned by dbo? How do I adjust it?

Comment: I've updated the script to handle non-dbo objects. I also changed it to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, which means that it should not only remain usable with future versions, but theoretically should work with Oracle, MySQL, etc. Finally, changed it to use `QUOTENAME` for all of the object names to handle things like spaces in table names.

Comment: It's not that unusual to be working with a database where no one in your company knows the schema.  I'm often being asked to query databases for software that our company purchased.  If the vendor is going to charge us for assistance, then it makes sense to see if you can figure out the schema without their help.

Comment: Extremely helpful. But I had to remove COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL condition as I was searching for UniqueIdentifiers

Comment: I was just handed the task to extract documents from a deprecated Document Management System (Objective, backend SQL Server 2005).  I'm a Linux admin, and pretty confident w/ Postgres, but know NOTHING about Objective & SQL server; exporting from within Objective is failing, there are no table relationships in the underlying database  ... where would I enter the code above in the GUI?

Comment: @tink I'm not familiar with Objective, but you can run this code in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which should have been installed when you installed the SQL Server instance or which can be installed locally as part of the SQL Server tools.

Answer (score 35):

I’d suggest you find yourself a 3rd party tool for this such as [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) (there are probably others out there too but I use this one because it’s free).

If you really want to go the SQL way you can try using stored procedure created by 
[Sorna Kumar Muthuraj](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c0c57332-8624-48c0-b4c3-5b31fe641c58) – copied code is below. Just execute this stored procedure for all tables in your schema (easy with dynamics SQL)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchTables 
 @Tablenames VARCHAR(500) 
,@SearchStr NVARCHAR(60) 
,@GenerateSQLOnly Bit = 0 
AS 

/* 
    Parameters and usage 

    @Tablenames        -- Provide a single table name or multiple table name with comma seperated.  
                        If left blank , it will check for all the tables in the database 
    @SearchStr        -- Provide the search string. Use the '%' to coin the search.  
                        EX : X%--- will give data staring with X 
                             %X--- will give data ending with X 
                             %X%--- will give data containig  X 
    @GenerateSQLOnly -- Provide 1 if you only want to generate the SQL statements without seraching the database.  
                        By default it is 0 and it will search. 

    Samples : 

    1. To search data in a table 

        EXEC SearchTables @Tablenames = 'T1' 
                         ,@SearchStr  = '%TEST%' 

        The above sample searches in table T1 with string containing TEST. 

    2. To search in a multiple table 

        EXEC SearchTables @Tablenames = 'T2' 
                         ,@SearchStr  = '%TEST%' 

        The above sample searches in tables T1 & T2 with string containing TEST. 

    3. To search in a all table 

        EXEC SearchTables @Tablenames = '%' 
                         ,@SearchStr  = '%TEST%' 

        The above sample searches in all table with string containing TEST. 

    4. Generate the SQL for the Select statements 

        EXEC SearchTables @Tablenames        = 'T1' 
                         ,@SearchStr        = '%TEST%' 
                         ,@GenerateSQLOnly    = 1 

*/ 

    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @CheckTableNames Table 
    ( 
    Tablename sysname 
    ) 

    DECLARE @SQLTbl TABLE 
    ( 
     Tablename        SYSNAME 
    ,WHEREClause    VARCHAR(MAX) 
    ,SQLStatement   VARCHAR(MAX) 
    ,Execstatus        BIT  
    ) 

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @tmpTblname sysname 

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@Tablenames)) IN ('' ,'%') 
    BEGIN 

        INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames 
        SELECT Name 
          FROM sys.tables 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@Tablenames,',',''' UNION SELECT ''') + '''' 

        INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames 
        EXEC(@sql) 

    END 

    INSERT INTO @SQLTbl 
    ( Tablename,WHEREClause) 
    SELECT SCh.name + '.' + ST.NAME, 
            ( 
                SELECT '[' + SC.name + ']' + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr + ''' OR ' + CHAR(10) 
                  FROM SYS.columns SC 
                  JOIN SYS.types STy 
                    ON STy.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id 
                   AND STy.user_type_id =SC.user_type_id 
                 WHERE STY.name in ('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar') 
                   AND SC.object_id = ST.object_id 
                 ORDER BY SC.name 
                FOR XML PATH('') 
            ) 
      FROM  SYS.tables ST 
      JOIN @CheckTableNames chktbls 
                ON chktbls.Tablename = ST.name  
      JOIN SYS.schemas SCh 
        ON ST.schema_id = SCh.schema_id 
     WHERE ST.name <> 'SearchTMP' 
      GROUP BY ST.object_id, SCh.name + '.' + ST.NAME ; 

      UPDATE @SQLTbl 
         SET SQLStatement = 'SELECT * INTO SearchTMP FROM ' + Tablename + ' WHERE ' + substring(WHEREClause,1,len(WHEREClause)-5) 

      DELETE FROM @SQLTbl 
       WHERE WHEREClause IS NULL 

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLTbl WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0) 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT TOP 1 @tmpTblname = Tablename , @sql = SQLStatement 
          FROM @SQLTbl  
         WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0 



         IF @GenerateSQLOnly = 0 
         BEGIN 

            IF OBJECT_ID('SearchTMP','U') IS NOT NULL 
                DROP TABLE SearchTMP 
            EXEC (@SQL) 

            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SearchTMP) 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT Tablename=@tmpTblname,* FROM SearchTMP 
            END 

         END 
         ELSE 
         BEGIN 
             PRINT REPLICATE('-',100) 
             PRINT @tmpTblname 
             PRINT REPLICATE('-',100) 
             PRINT replace(@sql,'INTO SearchTMP','') 
         END 

         UPDATE @SQLTbl 
            SET Execstatus = 1 
          WHERE Tablename = @tmpTblname 

    END 

    SET NOCOUNT OFF 

go
```

Comment: This stored proc is way more efficient than some of the other suggestions as it checks all the columns of a row in one select statement, but will not necessarily give you which cell the column matched. It also doesn't not presume that you want a full %wildcard% search. It also doesn't create any temporary tables, which is a hassle if not checked before before running the code.

If you aren't supposed to modify the db in which you're searching, simply convert the whole thing into a BEGIN / DECLARE / END block and keep it saved somewhere handy.

Comment: One more suggestion to users -- if the result set might be particularly large, and you just want to "start out" to see where things are, modify the above to include "TOP 100" limits or so.

Comment: I take my words back about it not creating temp tables .. it's a bit worse than that, even! A table, "SearchTMP", is created.

Answer (score 28):

Although the solutions presented before are valid and work, I humbly offer a code that's cleaner, more elegant, and with better performance, at least as I see it.

Firstly, one may ask: Why would anyone ever need a code snippet to globally and blindly look for a string? Hey, they already invented fulltext, don't you know?

My answer: my mainly work is at systems integration projects, and discovering where the data is written is important whenever I'm learning a new and undocummented database, which seldom happens.

Also, the code I present is a stripped down version of a more powerful and dangerous script that searches and REPLACES text throughout the database.

```
CREATE TABLE #result(
  id      INT IDENTITY, -- just for register seek order
  tblName VARCHAR(255),
  colName VARCHAR(255),
  qtRows  INT
)
go

DECLARE @toLookFor VARCHAR(255)
SET @toLookFor = '[input your search criteria here]'

DECLARE cCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT
  '[' + usr.name + '].[' + tbl.name + ']' AS tblName,
  '[' + col.name + ']' AS colName,
  LOWER(typ.name) AS typName
FROM
  sysobjects tbl
    INNER JOIN(
      syscolumns col
        INNER JOIN systypes typ
        ON typ.xtype = col.xtype
    )
    ON col.id = tbl.id
    --
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysusers usr
    ON usr.uid = tbl.uid

WHERE tbl.xtype = 'U'
  AND LOWER(typ.name) IN(
        'char', 'nchar',
        'varchar', 'nvarchar',
        'text', 'ntext'
      )
ORDER BY tbl.name, col.colorder
--
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @colName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @typName VARCHAR(255)
--
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @crlf CHAR(2)

SET @crlf = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

OPEN cCursor
FETCH cCursor
INTO @tblName, @colName, @typName

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
  IF @typName IN('text', 'ntext')
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = ''
    SET @sql = @sql + 'INSERT INTO #result(tblName, colName, qtRows)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT @tblName, @colName, COUNT(*)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'FROM ' + @tblName + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE PATINDEX(''%'' + @toLookFor + ''%'', ' + @colName + ') > 0' + @crlf
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = ''
    SET @sql = @sql + 'INSERT INTO #result(tblName, colName, qtRows)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT @tblName, @colName, COUNT(*)' + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'FROM ' + @tblName + @crlf
    SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE ' + @colName + ' LIKE ''%'' + @toLookFor + ''%''' + @crlf
  END

  EXECUTE sp_executesql
            @sql,
            N'@tblName varchar(255), @colName varchar(255), @toLookFor varchar(255)',
            @tblName, @colName, @toLookFor

  FETCH cCursor
  INTO @tblName, @colName, @typName
END

SELECT *
FROM #result
WHERE qtRows > 0
ORDER BY id
GO

DROP TABLE #result
go
```

Comment: This worked great for me in SQL Server 2012. Returned results in a couple of minutes

Comment: @Marcus Vinicius Pompeu Is it possible to use this same query to search for 2 strings?

Comment: Nevermind Marcus, the 2 strings I am looking for are exactly the same but the last character. I will just cut off the last character. Great answer by the way. +1

Comment: @EricS, you presented me a challenge! In two or three days I'll present us an even better solution. Regards.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu haha thank you and good luck. I will keep my open for it.

Answer (score 13):

If you are "getting data" from an application, the sensible thing would be to use the profiler and profile the database while running the application.  Trace it, then search the results for that string.

Answer (score 8):

The SSMS Tools PACK Add-In (Add-On) for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express will do exactly what you need. On larger database it takes some time to search, but that is to be expected. It also includes a ton of cool features that should have be included with SQL Server Management Studio in the first place. Give it a try [www.ssmstoolspack.com/](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Main.aspx)

You do need to have SP2 for SQL Server Management Studio installed to run the tools.

Answer (score 6):

I adapted a script originally written by [Narayana Vyas Kondreddi in 2002](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm). I changed the where clause to check text/ntext fields as well, by using patindex rather than like. I also changed the results table slightly. Unreasonably, I changed variable names, and aligned as I prefer (no disrespect to Mr. Kondretti). The user may want to change the data types searched. I used a global table to allow querying mid-processing, but a permanent table might be a smarter way to go.

```
/* original script by Narayana Vyas Kondreddi, 2002 */
/* adapted by Oliver Holloway, 2009 */

/* these lines can be replaced by use of input parameter for a proc */
declare @search_string varchar(1000);
set @search_string = 'what.you.are.searching.for';

/* create results table */
create table ##string_locations (
  table_name varchar(1000),
  field_name varchar(1000),
  field_value varchar(8000)
)
;
/* special settings */
set nocount on
;
/* declare variables */
declare
  @table_name varchar(1000),
  @field_name varchar(1000)
;
/* variable settings */
set @table_name = ''
;
set @search_string = QUOTENAME('%' + @search_string + '%','''')
;
/* for each table */
while @table_name is not null
begin

  set @field_name = ''
  set @table_name = (
    select MIN(QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name))
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where 
      table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and
      QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name) > @table_name and
      OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
  )

  /* for each string-ish field */
  while (@table_name is not null) and (@field_name is not null)
  begin
    set @field_name = (
      select MIN(QUOTENAME(column_name))
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      where 
        table_schema    = PARSENAME(@table_name, 2) and
        table_name  = PARSENAME(@table_name, 1) and
        data_type in ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'ntext') and
        QUOTENAME(column_name) > @field_name
    )

    /* search that field for the string supplied */
    if @field_name is not null
    begin
      insert into ##string_locations
      exec(
        'select ''' + @table_name + ''',''' + @field_name + ''',' + @field_name + 
        'from ' + @table_name + ' (nolock) ' +
        'where patindex(' + @search_string + ',' + @field_name + ') > 0'  /* patindex works with char & text */
      )
    end
    ;
  end
  ;
end
;

/* return results */
select table_name, field_name, field_value from ##string_locations (nolock)
;
/* drop temp table */
--drop table ##string_locations
;
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually Im agree with MikeW (+1) it's better to use profiler for this case.

Anyway, if you really need to grab all (n)varchar columns in db and make a search. See below.
I suppose to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables + dynamic SQL.
The plain search:

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(100) 
SET @SearchText = '12'
DECLARE @Tables TABLE(N INT, TableName VARCHAR(100), ColumnNamesCSV VARCHAR(2000), SQL VARCHAR(4000))

INSERT INTO @Tables (TableName, ColumnNamesCSV)
SELECT  T.TABLE_NAME AS TableName, 
        ( SELECT C.Column_Name + ',' 
          FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns C 
          WHERE  T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME 
                 AND C.DATA_TYPE IN ('nvarchar','varchar') 
                 FOR XML PATH('')
        )
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables T 

DELETE FROM @Tables WHERE ColumnNamesCSV IS NULL

INSERT INTO @Tables (N, TableName, ColumnNamesCSV)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TableName), TableName, ColumnNamesCSV  
FROM   @Tables

DELETE FROM @Tables WHERE N IS NULL

UPDATE @Tables 
SET ColumnNamesCSV = SUBSTRING(ColumnNamesCSV, 0, LEN(ColumnNamesCSV))

UPDATE @Tables 
SET SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ['+TableName+'] WHERE '''+@SearchText+''' IN ('+ColumnNamesCSV+')'

DECLARE @C INT, 
        @I INT, 
        @SQL VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @I = 1, 
       @C = COUNT(1) 
FROM   @Tables

WHILE @I <= @C BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = SQL FROM @Tables WHERE N = @I
    SET @I = @I+1
    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

and one with LIKE clause:

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(100) 
SET @SearchText = '12'

DECLARE @Tables TABLE(N INT, TableName VARCHAR(100), ColumnNamesCSVLike VARCHAR(2000), LIKESQL VARCHAR(4000))

INSERT INTO @Tables (TableName, ColumnNamesCSVLike)
SELECT   T.TABLE_NAME AS TableName, 
         (   SELECT  C.Column_Name + ' LIKE ''%'+@SearchText+'%'' OR ' 
             FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns C 
             WHERE   T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME 
                     AND C.DATA_TYPE IN ('nvarchar','varchar') 
          FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables T

DELETE FROM @Tables WHERE ColumnNamesCSVLike IS NULL

INSERT INTO @Tables (N, TableName, ColumnNamesCSVLike)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TableName), TableName, ColumnNamesCSVLike 
FROM @Tables

DELETE FROM @Tables WHERE N IS NULL

UPDATE @Tables 
SET  ColumnNamesCSVLike = SUBSTRING(ColumnNamesCSVLike, 0, LEN(ColumnNamesCSVLike)-2)

UPDATE @Tables SET LIKESQL = 'SELECT * FROM ['+TableName+'] WHERE '+ColumnNamesCSVLike

DECLARE @C INT, 
        @I INT, 
        @LIKESQL VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @I = 1, 
       @C = COUNT(1) 
FROM @Tables

WHILE @I <= @C BEGIN
    SELECT @LIKESQL = LIKESQL FROM @Tables WHERE N = @I
    SET @I = @I +1
    EXEC(@LIKESQL)
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Other answers posted already may work equally well or better, but I haven't used them.  However, the following SQL I have used, and it really helped me out when I was trying to reverse-engineer a big system with a huge (and very unorganzied) SQL Server database.

This isn't my code.  I wish I could credit the original author, but I can't find the link to the article anymore :(

```
Use 
go

declare @SearchChar varchar(8000)
Set @SearchChar =  -- Like 'A%', '11/11/2006'

declare @CMDMain varchar(8000), @CMDMainCount varchar(8000),@CMDJoin varchar(8000)
declare @ColumnName varchar(100),@TableName varchar(100)

declare dbTable cursor for 
SELECT 
Distinct b.Name as TableName
FROM 
sysobjects b
WHERE 
b.type='u' and b.Name  'dtproperties'
order by b.name
open dbTable
fetch next from dbTable into @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
declare db cursor for 
SELECT 
c.Name as ColumnName
FROM 
sysobjects b,
syscolumns c
WHERE 
C.id = b.id and
b.type='u' and b.Name = @TableName
order by b.name
open db
fetch next from db into @ColumnName
set @CMDMain = 'SELECT ' + char(39) + @TableName + char(39) + ' as TableName,'+ 
' ['+ @TableName + '].* FROM [' + @TableName + ']'+
' WHERE '
set @CMDMainCount = 'SELECT Count(*) FROM [' + @TableName + '] Where '
Set @CMDJoin = ''
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @CMDJoin = @CMDJoin + 'Convert(varchar(5000),[' +@ColumnName + ']) like ' + char(39) + @SearchChar + char(39) + ' OR '

fetch next from db into @ColumnName
end
close db
deallocate db

Set @CMDMainCount = 'If ('+ @CMDMainCount + Left(@CMDJoin, len(@CMDJoin) - 3)+ ') > 0 Begin '
Set @CMDMain = @CMDMainCount + @CMDMain + Left(@CMDJoin, len(@CMDJoin) - 3)
Set @CMDMain = @CMDMain + ' End '

Print @CMDMain

exec (@CMDMain)
fetch next from dbTable into @TableName
end
close dbTable
deallocate dbTable
```

Comment: RE: Link Maybe here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/SQLInsider+Scripts/31796/

Answer (score 3):

This uses no cursors or anything like that, just one dynamic query.

Also note that this uses `LIKE`. Since that happened to be what I needed. It works for all schemas, all tables and only query's those columns that are `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR` even if they have UDDT.

```
DECLARE @searchstring  NVARCHAR(255)
SET @searchstring = '%searchstring%'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = STUFF((
    SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS tablename, ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS columnname, ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS valuename' + 
    ' FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + 
    ' WHERE ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' LIKE ''' + @searchstring + ''''
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar', 'varchar')
    FOR XML PATH('')
) ,1, 11, '')

EXEC(@sql)
```

The output gives you the table, column and value. Time to execute on a small database was ~3 seconds, had about 3000 results.

Comment: When I run this I get the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.

Comment: @KarlGlennon I think, you need to change `AS table` to `AS [table]` and so on.

Comment: Note: results of this query includes views plus tables ;).

Comment: I am getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.`

Answer (score 3):

@NLwino, yery good query with a few errors for keyword usage. I had to modify it a little to wrap the keywords with [ ] and also look char and ntext columns.

```
    DECLARE @searchstring  NVARCHAR(255)
    SET @searchstring = '%WDB1014%'

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

    SELECT @sql = STUFF((
      SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS tbl, ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS col, [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] AS val' + 
        ' FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + TABLE_NAME + 
        '] WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + @searchstring + ''''
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'char', 'ntext')
                  FOR XML PATH('')
             ) ,1, 11, '')

    Exec (@sql)
```

I ran it on 2.5 GB database and it came back in 51 seconds

Comment: If this is an edit of @NLwino's post you should edit his post (when you have sufficient reputation) rather than posting a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be an easiest way to find a string in all rows of your database -without using *cursors* and *FOR XML*-.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPFindAll (@find VARCHAR(max) = '')
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(max) = ''

    SELECT  @query = @query + 
            CASE 
                WHEN @query = '' THEN '' 
                ELSE ' UNION ALL '
            END +
            'SELECT ''' + s.name + ''' As schemaName, ''' + t.name + ''' As tableName, ''' + c.name + ''' As ColumnName, [' + c.name + '] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT As [Data] FROM [' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + '] WHERE [' + c.name + '] Like ''%' + @find + '%'''
    FROM 
        sys.schemas s
        INNER JOIN
        sys.tables t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
        INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns c ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
        INNER JOIN
        sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
    WHERE
        ty.name LIKE '%char'

    EXEC(@query)
END
```

By creating this stored procedure you can run it for any string you want to find like this:

```
EXEC SPFindAll 'Hello World'
```

The result will be like this:

```
schemaName | tableName | columnName | Data
-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------------
schema1    | Table1    | Column1    | Hello World
schema1    | Table1    | Column1    | Hello World!
schema1    | Table2    | Column1    | I say "Hello World".
schema1    | Table2    | Column2    | Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
This procedure is for finding any string or date in all tables
if search string is date, its format should be yyyy-MM-dd
eg. 2011-07-05
*/

-- ================================================
-- Exec SearchInTables 'f6f56934-a5d4-4967-80a1-1a2223b9c7b1'

-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Joshy,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE SearchInTables
@myValue nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
        DECLARE @searchsql nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(1000)
        DECLARE @Schema_name nvarchar(1000)
        DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)
        DECLARE @XMLIn nvarchar(max)
        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@XMLOut varchar(max) OUTPUT'

        SELECT A.name,b.name 
        FROM sys.tables A 
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas B ON A.schema_id=B.schema_id
        WHERE A.name like 'tbl_Tax_Sections' 

        DECLARE tables_cur CURSOR FOR 
                            SELECT A.name,b.name FOM sys.tables A 
                            INNER JOIN sys.schemas B ON A.schema_id=B.schema_id
                            WHERE A.type = 'U'  
        OPEN tables_cur  
        FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name , @Schema_name 
            WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
            BEGIN
                SET @searchsql ='SELECT @XMLOut=(SELECT PATINDEX(''%'+ @myValue+ '%'''
                SET @searchsql =@searchsql  + ', (SELECT * FROM '+@Schema_name+'.'+@table_name+' FOR XML AUTO) ))'
                --print @searchsql 
                EXEC sp_executesql @searchsql, @ParmDefinition, @XMLOut=@XMLIn OUTPUT
                --print @XMLIn 

                IF @XMLIn <> 0 PRINT @Schema_name+'.'+@table_name

                FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name , @Schema_name 

            END
        CLOSE tables_cur 
        DEALLOCATE tables_cur 
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

To "find where the data I get comes from", you can start SQL Profiler, start your report or application, and you will see all the queries issued against your database.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use my query here, should be simpler then having to create sProcs for each DB you want to search: [FullParam SQL Blog](http://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/fck-it-i-am-going-to-search-all-tables-all-collumns/)

```
/* Reto Egeter, fullparam.wordpress.com */

DECLARE @SearchStrTableName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(255), @SearchStrInXML bit, @FullRowResult bit, @FullRowResultRows int
SET @SearchStrColumnValue = '%searchthis%' /* use LIKE syntax */
SET @FullRowResult = 1
SET @FullRowResultRows = 3
SET @SearchStrTableName = NULL /* NULL for all tables, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrColumnName = NULL /* NULL for all columns, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrInXML = 0 /* Searching XML data may be slow */

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results
CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(128), ColumnName nvarchar(128), ColumnValue nvarchar(max),ColumnType nvarchar(20))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = '',@ColumnName nvarchar(128),@ColumnType nvarchar(20), @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(110), @QuotedSearchStrColumnName nvarchar(110)
SET @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue = QUOTENAME(@SearchStrColumnValue,'''')
DECLARE @ColumnNameTable TABLE (COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(128),DATA_TYPE nvarchar(20))

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND TABLE_NAME LIKE COALESCE(@SearchStrTableName,TABLE_NAME)
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
    )
    IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @sql = 'SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),DATA_TYPE
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN (' + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SearchStrColumnValue,'%',''),'_',''),'[',''),']',''),'-','')) = 1 THEN '''tinyint'',''int'',''smallint'',''bigint'',''numeric'',''decimal'',''smallmoney'',''money'',' ELSE '' END + '''char'',''varchar'',''nchar'',''nvarchar'',''timestamp'',''uniqueidentifier''' + CASE @SearchStrInXML WHEN 1 THEN ',''xml''' ELSE '' END + ')
                AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE COALESCE(' + CASE WHEN @SearchStrColumnName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '''' + @SearchStrColumnName + '''' END  + ',COLUMN_NAME)'
        INSERT INTO @ColumnNameTable
        EXEC (@sql)
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME FROM @ColumnNameTable)
        BEGIN
            PRINT @ColumnName
            SELECT TOP 1 @ColumnName = COLUMN_NAME,@ColumnType = DATA_TYPE FROM @ColumnNameTable
            SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''',''' + @ColumnName + ''',' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'LEFT(CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 4096),''' 
            WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + '),'''
            ELSE 'LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 4096),''' END + @ColumnType + ''' 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))' 
                    WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
                    ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC(@sql)
            IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 IF @FullRowResult = 1 
            BEGIN
                SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@FullRowResultRows AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ''' + @TableName + ''' AS [TableFound],''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS [ColumnFound],''FullRow>'' AS [FullRow>],*' +
                    ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))' 
                    WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
                    ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
                EXEC(@sql)
            END
            DELETE FROM @ColumnNameTable WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
        END 
    END
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

SELECT TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM #Results
GROUP BY TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType

Answer (score 0):

This query can do the thing for you.

```
DECLARE
@search_string  VARCHAR(100),
@table_name     SYSNAME,
@table_id       INT,
@column_name    SYSNAME,
@sql_string     VARCHAR(2000)

SET @search_string = 'StringtoSearch'

DECLARE tables_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT ss.name +'.'+ so.name [name], object_id FROM sys.objects so INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss ON so.schema_id = ss.schema_id WHERE  type = 'U'

OPEN tables_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE columns_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = @table_id 
        AND system_type_id IN (167, 175, 231, 239, 99)

    OPEN columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @sql_string = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE [' + @column_name + '] 
            LIKE ''%' + @search_string + '%'') PRINT ''' + @table_name + ', ' + @column_name + ''''

            EXECUTE(@sql_string)

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
        END

    CLOSE columns_cur

DEALLOCATE columns_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id
END

CLOSE tables_cur
DEALLOCATE tables_cur
```