# how to find a sql field name that has a record like '%text%'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i want to search all teh fields in my DB to find the field names that have in them a string that contains some text.

im trying to find a table and field responsible for some 3rd party software actions that i am aonly able to see the values for. i want to use these values to find the table and field they are stored in.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591853/search-for-a-string-in-an-all-the-tables-rows-and-columns-of-a-db I swear someone asked this the other day as well and there was an SSMS addin suggested but I can't find that now.

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
select column_name,table_name
 from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%text%'
```

Misunderstood your question, see here: [Search all columns in all the tables in a database for a specific value](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2)

Comment: i dont care what the clounm name is i want the names of the columns that have a certain string od data with in records or data points of the coloumn. 

more like this:
select Col_Name where Col_Name.data = 'sometext'

i dont want fields called sometext... i want the records of the tables that have sometext to report to me the names of the fields that have this data.

Comment: In that case see here: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/05/sql-server-2005-get-field-name-and-type-of-database-table/

Answer (score -1):

I don't have specific answer.
But i use PHP code for MySQL that calls "show tables" and then for each table calls "show create table [table_name]"
I export the result to a text file and then search it...