# How to get a list of table names which has particular value in column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

We got a requirement in our application like this. To develop a powershell script to update computername in web.config file and in database tables.

This script will be executed if application was already installed but user has to change the computer name. [so even if machine name changed , our application which was installed will not break if he executed the script. No need to uninstall and reinstall the product]

Now lot of tables contains field which has computername in it. For ex. columns like URL, BaseURL contains computername then remaining texts.

I have to find the table names which has column value computername `(like column names URL and baseURL contains machine name.For example. AB2S481V0:80/Project/Default.aspx AB2S481V0 is the computername ).`

Finding the list by manually looking after each table is burdensome as many tables there. Is there any way to find the list of table names if i pass databasename and column substring(not the entire column name)

Comment: Probably this might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197299/sql-server-2008-find-which-tables-contain-specific-text

Answer (score 0):

I often search tables by column name, using this query:

```
USE MYDB
SELECT t.name, c.name
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%[my_serach_pattern]%'
```

The object_id refers to the table id inside the sys.tables (i.e. the object_id inside the sys.objects table).

Have a look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms189783.aspx) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.name as  [Table Name],b.name as [Column Name]
from sys.tables a
Join sys.columns b on a.object_id = b.object_id
where b.name like '%ColumnName%'
```