# How to search a given text in a table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to search a text in a table without knowing its attributes.
Example : I have a table Customer,and i want to search a record which contains 'mohit' in any field without knowing its column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for **[Full Text Indexing](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/)**

Example using the `Contains`

```
select ColumnName from TableName 
Where Contains(Col1,'mohit') OR contains(col2,'mohit')
```

**NOTE -** You can convert the above Free text query into dynamic Query using the column names calculated from the sys.Columns Query

Also check below

**[FIX: Full-Text Search Queries with CONTAINS Clause Search Across Columns](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294809)**

Also you can check all Column Name From below query

```
Select Name From sys.Columns Where Object_Id = 
                   (Select Object_Id from sys.Tables Where Name = 'TableName')
```

> Double-WildCard LIKE statements will not speed up the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna make a full search on the table, you must surely be knowing the structure of the table. Considering the table has fields `id`, `name`, `age`, and `address`, then your SQL Query should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM `Customer`
    WHERE `id` LIKE '%mohit%'
    OR `name` LIKE '%mohit%'
    OR `age` LIKE '%mohit%'
    OR `address` LIKE '%mohit%';
```

Comment: I dont the columns names, but i got my answer. I need to search the column name with respect to Customer first from syscolumns or from information schema.

Comment: This is MySQL syntax - column names in **SQL Server** T-SQL aren't delimited by back-ticks (`) ....

Comment: @marc_s I just put it for syntax highlighting purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Mohit, I'm glad you devised the solution by yourself.

Anyway, whenever you again face an unknown table or database, I think it will be very welcome the code snippet I just [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12557162/206413).

Ah, one more thing: the answers given did not addressed your problem, did they?