# Search Entire Database To find extended ascii codes in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have issues with extended ascii codes getting in our database (128-155)

Is there anyway to search the entire database and display the results of any of these characters that may be in there and where they are located within the tables and columns.

Hope that makes sense.

I have the script to search entire DB, but having trouble with opening line.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)

SET @SearchStr != between char(32) and char(127)
```

I have this originally that works, but I need to extend the range I'm looking for.

```
SET @SearchStr = '|' + char(9) + '|' + char(10) + '|' + char(13)
```

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to search with like? nvarchar is 16-bit characters I think so you might be better off iterating through strings and calling [`UNICODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) on each character then checking the return value of that is >= 32 and < 128.

Comment: ... and wouldn't it be better to enhance your client app to support non-ASCII characters? (assuming you've got consistent code sets everywhere)

Comment: Thanks for that also If I had control over the client app I would, don't worry that's been mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unclear what your data looks like, but this might help you to get started:

```
declare @TestData table (String nvarchar(100))

insert into @TestData select N'abc'
insert into @TestData select N'def'
insert into @TestData select char(128)
insert into @TestData select char(155)

declare @SearchPattern nvarchar(max) = N'%['
declare @i int = 128
while @i <= 155
begin
    set @SearchPattern += char(@i)
    set @i += 1
end
set @SearchPattern += N']%'

select @SearchPattern

select String
from @TestData
where String like @SearchPattern
```

Of course you'll need to add some code to loop over every table and column that you want to query (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591853/search-for-a-string-in-an-all-the-tables-rows-and-columns-of-a-sqll-server-db)), and it's possible that this code will behave differently on different collations.

Comment: `WHERE String LIKE N'%[^ -~]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN` would be simpler.

Comment: @MartinSmith Very nice! Although it will also include ASCII 0-31 and 127, which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

... where dodgyColumn is your column with questionable data ....

`WHERE(patindex('%[' + char(127) + '-' + char(255) + ']%', dodgyColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2) > 0)`

This works for us, to identify extended ASCII characters in our otherwise normal ASCII data (characters, numbers, punctuation, dollar and percent signs, etc.)